How to help users understand a markup language's grammar accessibly
How might I describe the grammar of a markup language in an accessible way?
What I have
SVG diagrams of the grammar (directed graphs). Each element page has a graph representing what content can be in each element. The SVG image is the only content on the page that does this. These images are generated from the grammar code.


Example page: Characters element https://docs.usfm.bible/usfm/3.1/char/index.html#_diagrams
Example SVG code: Characters element
Notice the textual labels
Figure
https://github.com/usfm-bible/tcdocs/blob/main/markers/images/schema/char_usx.svg?short_path=078b480
Problem
GitHub issue https://github.com/usfm-bible/docs.usfm.bible/issues/2
(presumably)

not A11y (screen reader) accessible
not searchable
not CTRL+F-able
not linked

Approaches I'm considering (not mutually exclusive)

output a graph markup language like PlantUML (used by Mermaid) https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/stateDiagram.html
turn the labels into links to the corresponding element's page
output a technical summary table, as in MDN's Content Categories, Permitted Content, and Permitted Parents. ( example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

How to help

How might you approach making these diagrams accessible for all?
How well do these SVG labels comply with WCAG best practices?


Provide plaintext.
When it comes to accessibility for diagrams you have to think about three groups of people:

Those who can visually work with your graphics or data
Those who can visually work with your data but cannot (or hardly) discern colors and need to zoom in to high levels (think 500% here)
Those who cannot see anything and have to resort to a screen reader.

Generally, if you have the topic Accessibility (A11y) in front of you as a developer, try to think "plaintext" instead for making a big step towards accessibility.
In your case, having a syntax to describe you would need to provide something like a plaintext list of allowed elements (I pick a simple and incomplete example from your SVG here):
char
  @*
  @style

@style
  vp
  qac
  qs
  ...

vp
  documentation/description what a vp is etc.

qac
  same for each terminal element.

Text
  CharEmbed
  Figure
  ...

Especially for syntax descriptions also check out the Extended Backus Naur Form. Providing an EBNF is a good start and helps everyone to work with the syntax description more effectively.
Advantages of plaintext: Searchable, easily accessible in the simplest of programs ("notepad"), text can be scaled at will or colors and contrast can be adapted by the user.
Disadvantage: You might want to add navigation to it. In this case a HTML file would be a sensible choice. You should however use it like plaintext mostly but indeed provide structural information where you can:

Provide headings <h1> <h2> etc.
Use numbering or bullet lists
Keep a close eye on alt tags
Provide paragraphs <p>
You can use tables if you use them to present data, do not use for layout purposes like columns of text or a sidebar menu.
Do not use colors (neither text nor backgrounds - those have to be adjustable by the user)
Do not use animations, collapsible things or any form of scripts. In fact: Don't use "design" elements, probably not even CSS.
Try to avoid the need to highlight things, but provide highlights - Meaning: avoid bold and italics <b> and <i> but use the <em> emphasize tag instead (screen readers will pronounce this text differently, more stressed)

Some details on screen readers and plaintext:
You can use some formatting:

indentations help all users
don't use bullet symbols like * or -
try to avoid separators like | / \
try to minimize special characters like @ and quotation marks " ' or any form of brackets [] () {}
Think of all text to be interpreted as lower case letters only (case insensitive). There is no difference in "TEXT" or "Text" or "text" or "CharEmbed" and "charembed".

You will notice that this makes EBNF in plaintext relying heavily on special charactes and case conventions a bad thing for screenreaders. But this can be improved with HTML or by carefully deciding which special characters are really needed.
Just to get an impression how a screen reader will present your file, enable that feature in your operating system and hear for yourself.
A word on WCAG compliance:
The SVG does not comply at all. The problem is that the diagrams convey structural information by the connecting lines. Group 3 cannot access/see them at all, Group 2 has a hard time following the lines and gain an overview.
The ideas you mentioned to improve things are mostly helping Group 1. This is a large group of course and a navigable diagram can be handy. The most benefit for all groups would be a simple HTML text file though.
